# Find the number of zero elements in a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a `NxM` matrix for example named `A`. After some processes I want to count the zero elements.
How can I do this in one line code? I tried `A==0` which returns a 2D matrix.

Answer (score 26):

There is a function to find the number of nonzero matrix elements `nnz`. You can use this function on a logical matrix, which will return the number of `true`.

In this case, we apply `nnz` on the matrix `A==0`, hence the elements of the logical matrix are `true`, if the original element was 0, `false` for any other element than 0.

```
A = [1, 3, 1;
     0, 0, 2;
     0, 2, 1];
nnz(A==0)  %// returns 3, i.e. the number of zeros of A (the amount of true in A==0)
```

The credits for the benchmarking belong to Divarkar.

---

## Benchmarking

Using the following paramters and inputs, one can benchmark the solutions presented here with `timeit`.

Input sizes

- Small sized datasize - `1:10:100`
- Medium sized datasize - `50:50:1000`
- Large sized datasize - `500:500:4000`

Varying % of zeros

- ~10% of zeros case - `A = round(rand(N)*5);`
- ~50% of zeros case - `A = rand(N);A(A<=0.5)=0;`
- ~90% of zeros case - `A = rand(N);A(A<=0.9)=0;`

The results are shown next -

**1) Small Datasizes**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**2. Medium Datasizes**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**3. Large Datasizes**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Observations**

1. If you look closely into the `NNZ` and `SUM` performance plots for medium and large datasizes, you would notice that their performances get closer to each other for `10%` and `90%` zeros cases. For `50%` zeros case, the performance gap between `SUM` and `NNZ` methods is comparatively wider.
2. As a general observation across all datasizes and all three fraction cases of zeros,
   `SUM` method seems to be the undisputed winner. Again, an interesting thing was observed here that the general case solution `sum(A(:)==0)` seems to be better in performance than `sum(~A(:))`.

Comment: This is the opposite of what the question asks for, i.e. the number of zero elements instead of nonzero elements. You would need to either do `numel(A) - nnz(A)` or else `nnz(~A(:))`

Comment: @Dan You are right...., i edited the answer so that it really answers the question.

Comment: The most efficient of this lot of solutions would be `nnz(A==0)`

Comment: @Divakar Thank you, obviously better. I changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Divakar Might be interesting to add the same chart with the x-axis limited to small vectors as you can't see that with the scale of the first chart. This could be useful information to someone performing this on a small matrix but many times.

Comment: @Divakar Thank you. The lines might be more intuitive to understand if plotted against N squared, as the number of elements increases with N squared. Interesting to see that the LENGTH-FIND and HISTC Method lines intersect quit often.

Comment: @Nras Well it states - `N as the datasize` and also mentions how the data is inputted into `A`, so that is coherent with the xlabel. So, I guess it's okay. But you are right in one way that it must have said Datasize as `N^2`.

Comment: +1 for the answer and the benchmarking. Small question, how would the `sum` vs `nnz` perform when there's a small (~1-5%) vs large (90~99%) # of zeros? in the benchmark you took ~50% zeros...

Comment: @natan added all those cases, take a look! I wish I could make a community wiki out of it, but then it's now a duplicate question.

Comment: very cool... so weird that `==0` is faster than `~` operator... this answer should definitely get more attention, maybe we should ask about making a community wiki out of it for this case in meta?

Comment: @natan Sounds like a plan! So do we need to ask on meta? Is that the part of the process?

Comment: yes, this will attract a moderator to respond to the matter.

Answer (score 15):

some basic matlab to know: the `(:)` operator will flatten any matrix into a column vector , `~` is the NOT operator flipping zeros to ones and non zero values to zero, then we just use sum:

```
sum(~A(:))
```

This should be also about **10** times faster than the `length(find...` scheme, in case efficiency is important.

**Edit:** in the case of NaN values you can resort to the solution:

```
sum(A(:)==0)
```

Comment: +1 - This is definitely more efficient

Comment: @rayryeng If the matrix have a `NaN` element you can not use `sum(~A(:))` because `NaN` cannot be converted to logical.

Comment: @NematollahZarmehi then use `sum(A(:)==0)`, same idea

Comment: @Dan +1 Great. That is right.

Comment: lol, I first did write `sum(A(:)==0)` and edited it to the `~A` option...

Comment: Or if you really insist on `~`, there's also `nansum(~A(:))`...

Comment: @Dev-iL - Nice fix, but `nansum` is only available in the Statistics Toolbox.

Comment: @rayryeng - You're technically right, but this function is very simple: `% Find NaNs and set them to zero.  Then sum up non-NaNs.  Cols of all NaNs will return zero.`

Comment: @Dev-iL - Yes of course, but I was just speaking in the spirit of one-liner answers :) `nansum` if you were to implement it yourself is not one line :(.  Still, a very good workaround.

Answer (score 4):

I'll add something to the mix as well.  You can use [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) and compute the histogram of the entire matrix.  You specify the second parameter to be which bins the numbers should be collected at.  If we just want to count the number of zeroes, we can simply specify `0` as the second parameter.  However, if you specify a matrix into `histc`, it will operate along the columns but we want to operate on the entire matrix.  As such, simply transform the matrix into a column vector `A(:)` and use `histc`.  In other words, do this:

```
histc(A(:), 0)
```

This should be equivalent to counting the number of zeroes in the entire matrix `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if I'm answering well the question but you could code it as follows :

```
    % Random Matrix
M = [1 0 4 8 0 6;
     0 0 7 4 8 0;
     8 7 4 0 6 0];

n = size(M,1); % Number of lines of M
p = size(M,2); % Number of columns of M

nbrOfZeros = 0; % counter

for i=1:n
    for j=1:p
        if M(i,j) == 0
            nbrOfZeros = nbrOfZeros + 1;
        end
    end
end

nbrOfZeros
```

Comment: Certainly a valid approach and the most canonical, but probably slow for very large matrices. You may get minor speedup if you only use one loop and use single linear accessing to grab elements.

Comment: @rayryeng Definitely yes to one loop. Works for N dimensions (as you know).  Good call. Conventional MATLAB wisdom says to avoid loops, but I'm surprised frequently at how good the JIT compilation has become.  Still, I'd only recommend this if memory were a big concern. Congrats on 20k!

Comment: @chappjc - Couldn't agree with you more!

Comment: @chappjc - Thanks for the congrats too :) :)