# script for calculating boundaries between elements of matrix

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

The following script gives me sum of boundaries of each element of matrix. boundaries are calculated about elements with value 1 that are next to each other. product of this summation named contact perimeter.

but Is there any other way that I can summarize or vectorize my raw and simple script? 
I ask this request because my real matrix is very large and use of "for" increase the time of calculation.

Thank you.

```
a1=[1 1 0 1 0 1;
    0 1 1 0 0 1;
    1 1 0 1 0 1;
    1 1 0 0 1 0;
    0 0 0 1 1 1]
m=5
n=6
cmp=zeros(m,n)
cmp1=zeros(m,n)
for i=1:m-1
    for j=1:n
        if a1(i,j)==a1(i+1,j) && a1(i,j)==1
            cmp(i,j)=1
        end
    end
    for i=1:m
        for j=1:n-1
            if a1(i,j)==a1(i,j+1) && a1(i,j)==1
                cmp1(i,j)=1
            end
        end
    end
end
cmtotal=cmp+cmp1
pc=sum(sum(cmtotal))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be pretty efficient one -

```
%// Case1 and case 2 matches
case1_matches = a1(1:end-1,:) == a1(2:end,:) & a1(1:end-1,:)==1
case2_matches = a1(:,1:end-1) == a1(:,2:end) & a1(:,1:end-1)==1

%// Get sum of those matches for the final output, equivalent to your pc
out = sum(case1_matches(:)) + sum(case2_matches(:))
```

You can replace the `sum(..(:))` with `nnz()`, but I doubt that it will be any better than `sum` in terms of runtime performance in accordance with **[benchmarks of `sum` against `nnz`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25322827/3293881)**.